# Using Java to open a mac application from terminal

Tags: java, terminal, escaping, backslash

Lets say I have this code

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test
{
 public static void main(String[] argv) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    String path = "/an app with spaces.app";
    path = path.replaceAll(" ", "\\\\ ");
    System.out.println(path);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open", path} );
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("syslog -s -l " + path);
 }
}
```

The thing is when I output the path in print and try the command in terminal, it opens the application, but when I try to execute the command from Java, it just closes, maybe it is an issue with escaping backslashes? Everything I want to do is open an app with spaces in its name, using terminal or not.

Answer (score 0):

No need to escape the spaces using `exec`.

I've tried your code, removing the `replaceAll`, and opening an application with spaces in the application name, **and** spaces in the containing directory, and the code launched the application.

Also, `syslog -l` requires a log level argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of Runtime.exec().